# Python en GNU Emacs 25 y primeros pasos

Tags: python, ubuntu, emacs

Tengo como sistema operativo Ubuntu 17.10, con todas sus actualizaciones. Quiero aprender a usar Python, para después pegar el salto, por mi cuenta, a Ruby o Perl. He leído que, en Ubuntu, Python se puede utilizar desde la consola o terminal, el problema es que no está en su última versión (3.6.4), sino en la 2.7.14, como aquí muestro:

```
usuario@usuario-ubuntu:~$ python 
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Entonces, yo trabajo con Haskell en GNU Emacs 25 (GUI) y me gustaría saber si se puede trabajar, es decir, escribir y compilar, Python en GNU Emacs 25 (GUI). He leído varios manuales en inglés, y sinceramente, no me entero mucho.

Para concluir, me gustaría, si pueden, que me recomendasen algún manual para aprender o páginas web en la que se publiquen ejercicios semanales o diarios para ir podiendo avanzar.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: La última parte de la pregunta está fuera de la temática de [es.so] , pero las referentes a python 3 y emacs son correctas. En SO no se recomiendan recursos (libros, manuales, librerías) porque es algo subjetivo y los enlaces pueden cambiar con el tiempo

Comment: Hola Mathandtic. Tu pregunta podria ser válida porque es en cuanto a configurar un entorno (emcas) para desarrollar en python. Sin embargo no muestras nada de lo investigado e intentado. Si te manejas un minimo en inglés, puedes probar en otro sitio de esta red: [emacs.se]. Para mejorar esta pregunta mira [ask] y [help/on-topic]. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En Ubuntu ya viene instalado Python 3.X, lo que pasa es que si pones en la línea de comandos `python` se ejecuta la versión 2.7.X.
Puedes comprobarlo con el comando `python3`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

$_
```

Por otro lado, [Emacs da soporte a Python sin ningún extra que instalar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs)